# Array of const static int

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, initialization, constants

I have variable in header:

```
const static int RED = 0;
const static int BLUE = 1;
const static int GREEN = 5;
const static int DOG = 8;
const static int CAT = 9;
const static int SNAKE = 7;
```

How can I create a global array and initialize them with the values of these `const` variables?

I tried:

```
const static int color[3] = {BLUE, GREEN, DOG};
const static int animal[3] = {DOG, CAT, SNAKE};
```

But compiler say error:

> initializer element is not constant

(I need to create some structure which I can loop over.)

Comment: Why not use enumerations instead?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Is it possible to loop over an enum that is not contiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is define them, so the values are constant at *compile time*:

```
#define RED 0
#define BLUE 1
#define GREEN 5

const static int color[3] = {BLUE, GREEN, DOG};
```

Or you could just set all elements in the array at runtime:

```
const static int color[3];
color[0] = BLUE;
color[1] = GREEN;
color[2] = DOG;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){ 
  if(color[i] == BLUE)
     printf("\nColor nr%d is blue", i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `C`, using `const` does not make a variable a compile time constant. It is called `const qualified.` So, you cannot use a `const` variable for initializing the other one in global scope.

Related, from `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, *Initialization*

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration
>   shall be constant expressions or string literals.

So, to get your job done, you can either make the `RED`, `BLUE` as MACROs (using `#define`), or, an enum, using these identifier names as enum constants.

Comment: Good explanation. BTW, when I tested the code with gcc (Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)), the compiler did not complain.it seems wired.